# Sharpe Ratio - Daily vs Annual

Tags: sharpe-ratio

How do I go from daily to annual sharpe?

Say I have an asset with average daily return of `0.1%` and a daily return standard deviation of `1%`.

My daily sharpe ratio is `0.1%/1% = 0.1`

Now let me annualize, assuming 365 trading days.
0.1% daily return is `(1+0.1%)^365 - 1 = 44%`  per year. (fixed, thanks commentors).
While 1% sd becomes `1%*sqrt(365) = 19.1%` annualized.

My annual sharpe is `44/19.1 = 2.30`

Now I think that's not correct, because others calculate yearly return linearly as `0.1% * 365` instead of compounding `(1.01)^365-1` but I don't see how that makes sense.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: It is unusual to compound the expected return. Instead the standard practice is that the return annualized is set to 365*0.1%. And since returns are usually measured per trading day it is standard to use 252 (the number of trading days) rather than 356 (the number of calendar days per year) as well. This is more about conventions than "what is right".

Comment: One thing you didn't do is subtract 1 from your compounded annualized return.

Comment: The asset trades 365 days. Why would it be a linear 0.1%*365 rather than the compounding returns of ((1+0.1%)^365 -1) ? Doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Hi: Atleast to me, it doesn't seem "fair" to compound the return and then leave the standard deviation alone. If one was going to compound the return, then it feels like the standard deviation should be based off of the compounded returns also. A second point is that, whether one compounds or not really depends on whether the returns made in one day are being re-invested the next day. If not, then the returns shouldn't be compounded.

Comment: Hi mark. We have a fixed amount of money invested, that grows/shrinks each day by the daily return. No money is taken out or put in. The returns are compounding. The standard deviation on a sample can't compound? I don't understand how you could calculate it differently.

Comment: Hi Paul: Why are the returns compounding ?  Are you taking the profits from day at time $t$ and throwing them back into the same strategy on the next day at $t + 1$. ?

Comment: Paul: Take the case where you had a billion dollars invested and were re-investing profits each day. So, suppose on day , the strategy returned 10 bps. So, you made a million dollars and you re-invest it. So, now you are investing 1 billion + 1 million on day $t+1$. .So, is the return on day $t+1$ calculated using 1 billion in the denominator or 1 billion + 1 million. IMHO, if you are going to include profits in the next day's strategy, the return on that day should use 1 billion + 1 million in the denominator. Otherwise, the return is getting artificially inflated by profits

Comment: Asset price by day
1000
1001
1002.001

Return each day 0.1%
Return total over 2 days 0.2001%, not 0.2%

I don't understand why you would ever not compound it?

Comment: Hi Paul: it seems that you're referring to the return due to an asset's price changes ? In that case, the concept of a sharpe ratio really doesn't apply. It sounds like you just want to compute the cumulative return of the asset, in which case, compounding is fine as as as long as you assume that there is a fixed amount of money invested in the asset at time $t_{0}$ and cash  never comes in or out of the investment in that asset. My apologies for confusion but sharpe ratio is usually (AFAIK)  computed using the returns to a strategy which is a very different framework.

Comment: Yes, cash never comes in or out. But why would it matter if it's a single asset investment, or a strategy consisting of several assets? In any case it's a strategy with daily as well as total returns.

Answer (score 1):

I think standard is to do sqrt(365) * daily Sharpe ratio

Comment: right ( or sqrt(252 ) but Paul was asking why isn't compounding used when going from daily to annual. I was saying that, if one compounds and doesn't handle the denominator change in the daily return, then this would overstate the numerator in the resuiting sharpe ratio. So, I don't think compounding is necessarily wrong but it would need to be done with care. Also, the compounded series results in a different return series so the volatility of the return series would change also.